# How to detect hostname + basename with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project which I share with someonelse.

I have my host set up as `http://dev.foobar` which maps to a folder called `foobar.com` and I have no issues with my code, it all works as intended.  However the other person has the same named folder foobar.com, but hasn't set up virtualhost, so he is using `http://localhost/foobar.com`

So, inside the code I have to send an ajax request to a URL `http://dev.foobar/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` however this won't work for the other guy, since his would be `http://localhost/foobar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`so right now I am using this code to get the host and append the url `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

```
function get_host() {
    if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
        var host = "https://localhost/foobar.com/";
    } else {
        var host = "https://" + window.location.hostname
    }
    return host
}
```

And I am send request to ajax like this

```
var ajaxURL = get_host() + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
```

The problem with the function is that I am hard-coding `foobar.com` and I am not sure if there is another way to do this

Comment: You know you can submit AJAX requests to relative URLs, right? Just `./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` will do just fine.

Comment: I tried that but it won't work for him. Because he has the php file in `http://localhost/foobar.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` whereas i have mine in `http://dev.foobar/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: Another alternative is rather than trying to do everything in JS, you can make it configurable on each system - for instance [Jenkins allows you to specify where it's reachable at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU18g.png), so it doesn't have to try to figure it out.

Comment: @JamesThorpe We are not at that level yet honestly. This is a simple prototype WP project, and it would be nice but unrealistic to start using/learning Jenkins for this particular issue.

Comment: `./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` will work if, for instance, you're in `http://localhost/foobar.com/index.php` - if you're in a subfolder or using "smart" URLs then it gets a little trickier since there's no way for JS to know the document root.

Comment: I'm not saying use Jenkins, I'm just using it as an illustration of an easy way to solve the problem - just have a config option to say what the base url is and use that everywhere.  If it really is just a prototype between the two of you, just hardcode it (it's either `localhost` or not) and move on.

Comment: I'm not sure I got all the core problem, but aren't you looking for the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element ? And to answer your question it's available under `document.baseURI`